# Angular 2 directive color not applied

Tags: angular

I have the following directive which applies color property

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[numberColor]'
})
export class NumberColorDirective implements OnChanges {
    @Input() numberValue: number;

    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer2) {
    }

    ngOnChanges(): void {
        if (this.numberValue > 0) {
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'color', 'green!important');
        }
        else if (this.numberValue < 0)
            this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'color', 'red!important');
    }
}
```

in html:

```
<td numberColor [numberValue]="TotalProfit">
                            {{TotalProfit}}
</td>
```

but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [RendererStyleFlags2](https://angular.io/api/core/RendererStyleFlags2) to add an `!important` style.

Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.ts#L182) they somehow expect you to add the `DashCase` flag as well, if you want to add the important flag:

```
this.renderer.setStyle(
  this.elRef.nativeElement, 
  'color', 
  'green', 
  RendererStyleFlags2.Important + RendererStyleFlags2.DashCase
);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but in dev tools I see that the red color I set is overriden by a style of the 3rd party component that I use and green is not important I have ```color:green``` in dev tools only

Comment: @pantonis I've updated my answer, apparently they have a bug when it comes to this, but maybe my workaround works for you :)